# Error in C executable file

Tags: c, executable

My program is up to date and works fine when I am running on Turbo C.
Once I compile and run the program, executable file gets created. 
When I run executable file it should work, but for following program it always gives "false" answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *BoyerMoore( unsigned char *data, unsigned int dataLength, unsigned char *string, unsigned int strLength )
{
    unsigned int skipTable[256], i;
    unsigned char *search;
    register unsigned char lastChar;

    if (strLength == 0)
    return NULL;

    // Initialize skip lookup table
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    skipTable[i] = strLength;

    search = string;

    // Decrease strLength here to make it an index
    i = --strLength;

    do
    {
    skipTable[*search++] = i;
    } while (i--);

    lastChar = *--search;

    // Start searching, position pointer at possible end of string.
    search = data + strLength;
    dataLength -= strLength+(strLength-1);

    while ((int)dataLength > 0 )
    {
    unsigned int skip;

    skip = skipTable[*search];
    search += skip;
    dataLength -= skip;
    skip = skipTable[*search];
    search += skip;
    dataLength -= skip;
    skip = skipTable[*search];

    if (*search != lastChar) /*if (skip > 0)*/
    {
        // Character does not match, realign string and try again
        search += skip;
        dataLength -= skip;
        continue;
    }

    // We had a match, we could be at the end of the string
    i = strLength;

    do
    {
        // Have we found the entire string?
        if (i-- == 0)
        return search;
    } while (*--search == string[i]);

    // Skip past the part of the string that we scanned already
    search += (strLength - i + 1);
    dataLength--;
    }

    // We reached the end of the data, and didn't find the string
    return NULL;
}
void chomp(char *s) {
    int n = strlen(s);
    while (n && (s[n-1]==10 || s[n-1]==13)) s[--n] = 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    char target[200];
    char *ch = target,*str;
    char pattern[20];
    int i,k,count,l;
    chomp(target);
    chomp(pattern);
    str = BoyerMoore( target, strlen(target), pattern, strlen(pattern) );
    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    fgets(target,100,stdin);
    //scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", target);
    printf("Enter the string to be matched: \n");
    fgets(pattern,20,stdin);
    //scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", pattern);


    if (str == NULL)
    puts( "String not found" );
    else
    puts( "true" );
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is called a semantic error. Have you tried running the code in a debugger to get informed about its state at specific points in the execution? That would surely help.

Answer (score 1):

The calls to `chomp` are being passed arrays of uninitialised chars.  The calls to `strlen` will then have undefined results, including very possibly reading/writing beyond the end of your buffers.

After this, you call `BoyerMoore`, passing in these still (at least partially) uninitialised buffers.

After this, you read `pattern` and `target` but don't do anything with them.

You don't say what the code is supposed to do but at the least I guess you need to

- remove the calls to `chomp`
- call `fgets` to initialise `pattern` and `target` before calling `BoyerMoore`

If things don't work after this, try using a debugger or adding `printf` statements to trace program progress.